# \verb not working in beamer even though I use [fragile]

Tags: beamer, verbatim, uncover

Just trying to display a command like \section{} in the presentation, but \verb doesn't work. It works without the \uncover{}, but is there anyway to get around that?

```
\documentclass[t,xcolor=dvipsnames,table,ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Why does this not work?}

\uncover<+->{\begin{block}{Zum Beispiel...}
\begin{itemize}
\uncover<+->{\item Just trying to show something like \verb|\section{}|}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\verb` does not work as argument to another command.

But in `beamer` both `\begin{block}` and `\item` accept a `<+->` argument, so you can use that instead of `\uncover`:

```
\documentclass[t,xcolor=dvipsnames,table,ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Why does this not work?}

\begin{block}<+->{Zum Beispiel...}
\begin{itemize}
  \item<+-> Just trying to show something like \verb|\section{}|
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

> [image] [image]